# Possible to write XML reading code that will run on Python and IronPython?

Tags: python, xml, ironpython

I am writing code to parse XML (actually, KML) files and load them to a database.  I would like to run the code under either Python or IronPython.

Unfortunately, I find that `xml.dom.minidom` will not load under IronPython because it has a dependency on expat.py, which is not implemented on IronPython.  I also tried using `try / except` blocks to get an XML document object from either platform.  Although I can obtain a document gracefully running under either platform the internal implementations of the documents are too different to write code that runs under either platform.

Is there an XML parsing strategy that is compatible across Python and IronPython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this webpage](http://foolish-assertions.blogspot.com/2009/12/spare-batteries-for-ironpython.html), you may be able to get `xml.dom.minidom` running (if the only missing part is `expat.py`):

*"Download FePy's [pyexpat.py](https://fepy.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/fepy/trunk/lib/pyexpat.py), copy it to IronPython's Lib/xml/parsers subdirectory, and rename it to expat.py."*

Related: http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/20023

Comment: Thanks!  One step missing on that web page — you must also copy (from the standard Python library) xml.dom.expatbuilder.py.  With those two changes made, my code runs on both platforms!